# WEKA - RandomForest how to know when the tree is too deep?

Tags: tree, machine-learning, random-forest

I've just started working with Weka and I cannot get to understand when my decision trees are too deep. 
I have  a set of 423 features which, as far as I know, are randomnly chosen for every single goal. So these subsets of features generate branches or flows with decision leaves that do not seem to be generic, in fact they are too specific since they apply for only one or two cases of all the cases in the corpus, e.g.,no (2/0), yes (1/0).
I believe it's not generalizing well and maybe this is due to the fact that the decision trees are too deep. So my question is, which should be the maxDepth of the tree? How do I know when the tree is too deep? I tried but changing the maxDepth to 10 and still the leaves contain decisions based on few cases.
Also, by default Weka generates 10 trees and I wonder whether setting a bigger number of trees would bring me better results. I've read that random forest works well with 100,300 or even 500 trees, though I don't know if that would work for a set of 423 features. 
Finally, I'd like to know what does "1" means in this decision: "no (632/1)". Does it mean that 632 were correctly classified as "no" but one was classified as "yes" even though it was "no" ? Is that "1" a false positive?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to try out in such a scenario will be to do a grid search over the parameters. So you can decide on a performance metric and find out the value of it for varying parameters. This will be beneficial for deciding on the optimum parameter setting. Also try to calculate that performance metric on a validation set rather than the training set.